# Coded UI for Sharepoint Portals

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I am new for Coded UI. We want to use Coded UI to test Sharepoint portals.While running few tests, we came across the following questions.

1. How does it support if control Id's are generated dynamically?
2. How much support does it give to test Sharepoint out of box features?
3. Does it support Third-party asp.net controls?

Please let me know if you have any conclusion for these questions and also share the limitations of Coded UI for Sharepoint features.

Please provided useful links if any.

Answer (score 2):

```
How does it support if control Id's are generated dynamically?
```

We have a (non Sharpoint) project with this situation. No problems until now. The record-tool finds normally enough informations (name, position, content, parent) to identify the control.

> How much support does it give to test Sharepoint out of box features?

Sorry I haven't expirience to this, but can't imaging that there are to many problems.

> Does it support Third-party asp.net controls?

Yes. We use controls form DevExpress - works fine.

> Links

In this case I can really recommend you the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286726%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) Pages to this topic. They provide some good hints in context of working with CUIT.

Comment: Thanks for you reply.

Please give the searching criteria you used to identify control those Id's are generated dynamically in your project.

Comment: There is no universal answer to his. Mostly I take that what the record generates. Only sometimes I have to delete a generated criteria (very rarely).